# Unexpected mongo exit code 100 Happens Only When Someone Else Tries to Open My App Using localhost

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on an assignment and depend on peer reviews for a grade. I don't get this error (and no errors in console), but my reviewer can't run my app in localhost on her machine and gets:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting. 
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting. 
Can't start Mongo server. 
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
```

Is it a problem on my end?

Comment: Does the install of Mongo on the reviewers machine have the correct permissions set up? That error give plenty of potential solutions.

Comment: Also try starting Mongo from the command line, you may get more debug info.

Comment: Don't know if reviewers machine has correct permissions and am not likely to be able to get the info.

Comment: Don't mean to be so dense, but how do I start mongo from command line?

Comment: I have no idea go look it up. I figured that out from simple Googling the error you posted!

Comment: I did just that and wasn't able to connect. I'll keep reading/trying but thought you might know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, `sudo mongod` should start your local server for you. I'm not sure since I'm not a Windows user what to do there.

Comment: Thanks for responding J2. I guess I just don't understand. Local server and MongoDB running without errors on my MacBookPro. Was wondering why someone on another machine might get the errors I originally posted as I must depend on them to give me a peer reviewed grade.

Comment: I just reread your op. I wonder if the user who is trying to use your app has mongo installed correctly and running on their machine. Should their instance of mongo be local to their machine or would it be on a server online?

Comment: Thank you for responding J2. It would be local to their machine as there is no online server set up for the class. We download the apps to our machines and run in localhost.

Comment: Perhaps their instance of mongo is not up and running?

Comment: That's what I was beginning to think too.

Comment: I guess have them check that to start. Of course make sure MongoDb is installed on their machine to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. It's the only option left as I've been doing cartwheels all day thinking it was something on my end, but I see no evidence of that.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up to say you were correct. That reviewer didn't have mongo installed correctly. 2 other reviewers were able to open and run my app. But, because of that 1 reviewer, I didn't get a passing grade and have to retake the class!

Comment: Ugh that stinks. At least for the future, you will know should you or someone else get that error, you'll know why.